# Product collection by attriubte base in magento

Tags: magento, collections, product

I want to get the product collection in magento.For that i use some code but i think this code is not what i need.I want to get collection on attribute base.I got some products but it didn't match to those products that are filters from advance results for that attribute.Means different results from my collection and advance search results.Also the product url is not valid one.May be someone know where is the problem ? thanks in advance.My code is :

```
<?php $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter(array(
    array('attribute'=>'manufacturer','eq'=>'23'),
));
foreach ($collection as $product) {
     ?>
                <div class="brand_name">
                    <p>Audi</p>
                    <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl();?>"><?php echo substr($product->getName(),0,10);?></a>
                </div>

                <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work correctly:

```
$attrToSelect = '*'; // or Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes();
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect($attrToSelect)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', 23)
;

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getProductUrl();
}
```

Also check in admin - Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes - Used in Product Listing set Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You have used 2 `array` in the field to filter. Try with one.

`<?php $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute'=>'manufacturer','eq'=>'23');`

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I got this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) in `

Comment: @Adda can you verify if the error is because of this line of code itself or if it is because of some other code?

Comment: You are trying to pass array elements without array.`->addFieldToFilter('attribute'=>'manufacturer','eq'=>'23')`.See this sentence .

Comment: @Adda you are right, my bad. Eventhough I have mention to use one array in my ansewer i omitted `array` in my code, sorry. Does it works for you now?

Answer (score -1):

please use `addAttributeToFilter('manufucture',23)`

instead of

`adfieldtofilter`

Comment: Reined xiong the product and catalog and attri

Comment: Nothing happened with re-indexing.